# Mixed integer programming looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, mixed-integer-programming

I have a mixed integer program with 25 constraints with three subscript variables. There are two types of variables one are integer and one are binary.
Integer variables are called Axyz and binary are called Bxyz. Here is my formulation:

objective A111 + A112 + A113 + A211 + A212 + A213 + ... A252525  <-- This last one is the problem. I can't put it like this. So I would need to change all of them to three digit subscript for one subscript. What I mean is A111 becomes A001001001 and A252525 becomes A025025025, so that the compiler can read it.

constraints: 1st constraint
A111 + 90 B111 <= 0
A112 + 90 B112 <= 0
Same problem would be here as optimization function. And how do I make this constraint output.

2nd constraint:
A111 + A112 + A113 + A211 + A212 + A213 + ... A252525 >= 1000 Make it output.How to code this?

The only code I have so far is for the objective and that only works partially because of that A252525 problem. Here it is:

```
from itertools import product

num = "".join(map(str, range(1, 25)))
l = map(lambda x: 'A' + x, (map('1'.join, product(num, num))))

print (" + ".join(l))
```

If you run this then you will see that it starts to repeat after A119 because of the range. To understand what I want, you must run the code.

I want the output to look exactly like the following. And obviously those ... is upto where I want it. The output would actually have everything in between.

```
A111 + A112 + A113 + A211 + A212 + A213 + ... A252525
A111 + 90 B111 <= 0 
A112 + 90 B112 <= 0 ... A252525 + 90 B252525 <= 0
A111 + A112 + A113 + A211 + A212 + A213 + ... A252525 >= 1000
```

---

UPDATED:

Here is the exact output I want:

```
A010101 + A010102 + A010103 + A010104 + A010105 + A010106 + A010107 + A010108 + A010109 + A010110 + A020101 + A020102 + A020103 + A020104 + A020105 + A020106 + A020107 + A020108 + A020109 + A020110 + A030101 + A030102 + A030103 + A030104 + A030105 + A030106 + A030107 + A030108 + A030109 + A030110 + A010201 + A010202 + ....... + A030210
```

x represents the day of the week (We are assuming for this 3 days)
y represents the week (We are assuming 2 weeks)
z represents the salesman (We are assuming 10 salesman)

It's like saying on day 1 of week 1 salesman 1 is working, and so on.
In the output that I want, as mentioned before there are three subscripts; xyz. So in the output that I want, each of those subscripts represent the first two, second two, and third two numbers, respectively. For ex: For the first term, x is 01, y is 01, and z is 01 as well, and for the last term x is 03, y is 02, and z is 10. What I did forget to mention is that I want the user to enter the values for x, y, and z. For I want the user would have entered x=3,y=2,and z=10 (This is what represents the last term). I am assuming that's how it would be. The "y" 02 will only start once all the 01 for "y" are complete, which would be A030110. See this in sample output.

Then for the 1st set of constraints, it needs to be like:

```
A010101 + 90 B010101 <= 0
A010102 + 90 B010102 <= 0
```

and this would go on for every single term in the objective.

Don't worry about the 2nd set of constraints. And you don't need to know what constraints mean. Here you don't need to know what it means.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't really understand what the purpose is of what you're doing.

Regardless, this following will generate  the exact output you say you want. I don't like the way `permutations()` is hardcoded and it's a hack, but produces the permutations of the digits ordered the way you wanted.

```
def permutations(*args):
    assert len(args) == 3
    for y in args[1]:
        for x in args[0]:
            for z in args[2]:
                yield ''.join([x, y, z])

two_digit_string = lambda x: '{:02d}'.format(x)

NUM_DOW, NUM_WEEK, NUM_SALESMEN = 3, 2, 10
dows = tuple(two_digit_string(x) for x in range(1, NUM_DOW+1))
weeks = tuple(two_digit_string(x) for x in range(1, NUM_WEEK+1))
salesmen = tuple(two_digit_string(x) for x in range(1, NUM_SALESMEN+1))

l = ('A'+''.join(digits) for digits in permutations(dows, weeks, salesmen))
print(' + '.join(l))
```

Output:

```
A010101 + A010102 + A010103 + A010104 + A010105 + A010106 + A010107 + A010108 + A010109 + A010110 +
A020101 + A020102 + A020103 + A020104 + A020105 + A020106 + A020107 + A020108 + A020109 + A020110 +
A030101 + A030102 + A030103 + A030104 + A030105 + A030106 + A030107 + A030108 + A030109 + A030110 +
A010201 + A010202 + A010203 + A010204 + A010205 + A010206 + A010207 + A010208 + A010209 + A010210 +
A020201 + A020202 + A020203 + A020204 + A020205 + A020206 + A020207 + A020208 + A020209 + A020210 +
A030201 + A030202 + A030203 + A030204 + A030205 + A030206 + A030207 + A030208 + A030209 + A030210
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything. It just runs the code. There is no output at all.

Comment: There's a `print()` function call that will display something like what is shown. If there isn't, you've changed something.

Comment: I haven't changed anything. Did you run this code, and it worked for you?

Comment: Yes, it's how the output shown in my answer was generated. Just did it again (using Python 2.7.13). However appears not to do anything when run with Python 3.6.0. What are you using?

Comment: For Python 3.x, use `num = list(map(lambda x: format(x, '02d'), range(1, 26)))`

Comment: Yes sir. That's what it was. I am using python 3.6

Comment: As in my question, how would I do the 1st constraint with that inequality. So `A111 + 90 B111 <= 0`  <-- this is the first line, and second line would be the next one, and so on for the remaining ones. But they all be on different lines.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you want. What are the "ones" are you talking about? What's a constraint?

Comment: The output is still incorrect. In the objective we need A010101 + A010102. This is okay upto A010125 in the output, but after that it should be A020101, and you have A010201. And I want it to go upto A050425.

Comment: That's just how the `product()` function works. You can check out the equivalent Python code for it in the documentation. Using that and my answer as an example, perhaps you can figure it out yourself now.

Comment: Just one last question. What is `num,num,num` in the code. What does it print?

Comment: They're the three things that `product()` produces all the  permutations of.

Comment: I am confused. I will have to add a lot more to your code to do what I want. It's back to square one. I ended up where I was before you helped me out. I would appreciate if you can help me

Comment: I'm working on an answer to another question at the moment. Perhaps you could edit your question and explain exactly what the inputs and outputs are you want. I strongly suspect mentioning "constraints" doesn't convey much information (too most folks anyway) with regards to writing some code to perform the task.

Comment: Okay. I will change the question as much as possible. Thanks

Comment: Do you think you could also tell me how to do the 1st constraint?

Comment: Probably. To be clear: you just want to output separate lines with `A111 + 90 B111 <= 0` followed by `A112 + 90 B112 <= 0 ` sequentially up to `A242424 + 90 B242424 <= 0` and lastly by `A252525 + 90 B252525 <= 0`? For one thing it seems like they should be in form something like  `A111 + 90 * B111 <= 0` to be a valid Python conditional expressions. Also, what about the 2 digit "indexes"?

Comment: Actually, I will comment back on here after few days, and let you know about it.